# Showing the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \geq j; n > n_{j-1} \}$ is non-empty. Terence Tao 6.6.3

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Terrence Tao exercise  6.6.3**

> Let $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a sequence which is not bounded. Show that there exists a subsequence $(b_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ of $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{b_n}$ exists and is equal to zero. (Hint: for each natural number $j$, recursively introduce the quantity $n_j := \min \{n \in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \geq j; n > n_{j-1}  \}$ (omitting the condition when $n > n_{j-1}$ when $j = 0$), first explaining why the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \geq j; n > n_{j-1}  \}$ is non-empty. Then set $b_j := a_{n_j}$.

Can someone please comment on the proof where we need to show that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \geq j; n > n_{j-1}  \}$ is non-empty. Here is my attempt:

If $j = 0$ this is trivial.

We will consider the case that $j \ge 1$ we need to show that |$a_N$| $\ge $ j and N > $N_{j-1}$ for some natural number N (since this is exactly what it means to be a member of the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \geq j; n > n_{j-1}  \}$)

Consider the natural number denoted $N_{j-1}$

We know $N_{j-1}$ + $1$ > $N_{j-1}$ since $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is unbounded then $(a_n)_{n=N_{j-1} + 1}^{\infty}$ is unbounded so there exists some N such that
$N \ge N_{j-1} + 1 > N_{j-1}$ where  $a_N$ $\ge$ j hence |$a_N$| $\ge $ j and N > $N_{j-1}$ so it follows that N is a element of $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: |a_n| \geq j; n > n_{j-1}  \}$